# Date-time as an identification and insert to the sql server

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I would like to use the date as an identification that will link two different tables together. I've searched a lot and found a few alternative solutions but I get error messages like this:

```
 pyodbc.Error: ('21S01', '[21S01] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement. (109) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

This is the code I work with:

```
from src.server.connectToDB import get_sql_conn
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cursor = get_sql_conn().cursor()
    localFile = 'C:\\Users\\dersimw\\Source\Repos\\nordpoolAnalyse\\data\\2011-3.xlsx'
    excelFile = pd.ExcelFile(localFile)
    rowsID = []

a = ["01"]
for sheets in a:
    df = excelFile.parse(sheets).head(5)
    df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    print(df)

    now = datetime.now()
    DateDateTime = now.strftime('?Y-?m-?d ?H:?M:?S')


    for key, rows in df.items():
        print("## Column: ", key, "\n")
        columnInsertSql = "INSERT INTO Table11 (DateDateTime, AcceptedBlockBuy, AcceptedBlockSell,  RejectedBlockBuy, RejectedBlockSell, NetImports) VALUES("
        columnCounter = 1
        columnHasData = False

        for key, column in rows.items():
            if isinstance(column, int) or isinstance(column, float):
                columnHasData = True
                columnInsertSql += str(column)

                if columnCounter != len(list(rows.items())):
                    columnInsertSql += ", "
                    columnCounter += 1
        columnInsertSql += ")"

        if columnHasData == True:
            cursor.execute(columnInsertSql)
            cursor.commit()
```

This what I have:

```
Id    A.BlockBuy A.BlockSell  R.BlockBuy R.BlockSell NetImports
1      112       1             14          655       65
2      123       1             54          3         654
3      122       1             65          43        43
. 
.
122    21       12            54          54        54
```

This is what I want:

```
Id DateDate   A.BlockBuy A.BlockSell  R.BlockBuy R.BlockSell NetImports
1  2018-08-1   112       1             14          655       65
2  2018-08-1   123       1             54          3         654
3  2018-08-1   122       1             65          43        43
. 
.
122 2018-08-01  21       12            54          54        54
```

Comment: Plz indent your code properly so that others can simply copy paste it and help you more efficiently

Comment: You are appending data values into your command text, a process known as "dynamic SQL". That is usually *not* a good idea. Since you already have most of the data in a DataFrame you should be able to add a date/time column and then use pandas' `to_sql` method to perform the inserts.

Comment: The error you are seeing is simply saying you have more columns specified in the insert clause than supplied values. There is likely a logic issue within the `for key, column in rows.items():` loop, where you should be adding an extra column. To check, just output the value for `columnInsertSql` instead of executing it, and you should see the issue. It looks like you're not specifying a value for the `datedatetime`. Either specify a value, or remove the column from your clause and have a default.

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/ Your code is wide open to sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying is not a good way to do etl. I have build my own package for one of my project using postgres and python. The procedure should be exactly same for SQL Server.  You should add a datetime column to your data (etl_run_time ). I always add it to the dataframe/data before I upload into database. Then I can do bulk insert to the database.

The main thing is, The data loading to python and insertion to database should be separate task. Then there should be some update task if needed. I could not manage time to replicate exactly your task. But You can read in detail into the blog: https://datapsycho.github.io/PsychoBlog/dataparrot-18-01

```
# import datetime
import time
# from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import json
# that function has username and password for db connection
# you can create your own which will be used as cursor
from auths.auth import db_connection 
import os
import pandas as pd

class DataLoader():
    # function to process survey sent data
    @classmethod
    def process_survey_sent_data(cls):
        # my file path is very big so I divide it to 3 different part
        input_path_1 = r'path\to\your\file'
        input_path_2 = r'\path\to\your\file'
        input_path_3 = r'\path\to\your\file'
        file_path = input_path_1 + input_path_2 + input_path_3
        file_list = os.listdir(os.path.join(file_path))
        file_list = [file_name for file_name in file_list if '.txt' in file_name]
        field_names = ['country', 'ticket_id']
        pd_list = []
        for file_name in file_list:
            # collecting file name to put them as column
            date_ = file_name.replace(" ", "-")[:-4]
            file_path_ = file_path + '\\' + file_name
            df_ = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(file_path_), sep='\t', usecols=field_names).assign(sent_date=date_)
            df_['sent_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_['sent_date'])
            df_['sent_date'] = df_['sent_date'].values.astype('datetime64[M]')
            df_['sent_date'] = df_['sent_date'].astype(str)
            pd_list.append(df_)
        df_ = pd.concat(pd_list)
        # doing few more cleaning 
        # creating a unique ID
        df_ = df_[['country','sent_date', 'ticket_id']].groupby(['country','sent_date']).agg('count').reset_index()
        df_['sent_id'] = df_['country'] + '_' + df_['sent_date']
        df_.drop_duplicates(keep='first', subset='sent_id')
        print(df_.head())
        output_path_1 = r'\\long\output\path1'
        output_path_2 = r'\lont\output\path2'
        output_path = output_path_1 + output_path_2
        # put the file name
        survey_sent_file = 'survey_sent.json'
        # add etl run time
        df_['etl_run_time'] = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        # write file to json
        df_.to_json(os.path.join(output_path, survey_sent_file), orient='records')
        return print('Survey Sent data stored as json dump')


    # function to crate a database insert query
    @classmethod
    def insert_string(cls, column_list,table_name):
        # Uncomment the first part in the console
        first_part = 'INSERT INTO {} VALUES ('.format(table_name)
        second_part = ', '.join(['%({})s'.format(col) for col in column_list])
        return first_part + second_part + ') ;'

    # function to execute database query
    @classmethod
    def empty_table(cls, table_name):
            conn = db_connection()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("delete from {} ;".format(table_name))
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()

#    #function to run post post_sql code after the data load
#    @classmethod
#    def run_post_sql(cls):
#        # create a database query which can run after the insertation of data
#        post_sql = """
#        INSERT INTO schema.target_table  -- target
#        select * from schema.extract_table  -- extract
#        WHERE
#           schema.extract_table.sent_id -- primary key of extract
#           NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT sent_id FROM schema.target_table) -- not in target
#        """
#        conn = db_connection()
#        cursor = conn.cursor()
#        cursor.execute(post_sql)
#        conn.commit()
#        conn.close()
#        return print("Post SQL for servey sent has run for Survey Sent.")

    # function to insert data to server
    @classmethod
    def insert_survey_sent_data(cls):
        output_path_1 = r'new\json\file\path1'
        output_path_2 = r'\new\json\file\path2'
        output_path = output_path_1 + output_path_2
        ## create file
        output_survey_file = 'survey_sent.json'
        full_path = os.path.join(output_path, output_survey_file)

        # column name from the json file
        table_def = ['sent_id','country', 'ticket_id', 'sent_date', 'etl_run_time']
        # load the data as json and partitioning
        with open(full_path, 'r') as file:
            chunk = 60
            json_data = json.loads(file.read())
            json_data = [json_data[i * chunk:(i + 1) * chunk] for i in range((len(json_data) + chunk - 1) // chunk )]

        # create connection delete existing data and insert data
        table_name = 'schema.extract_table'
        cls.empty_table(table_name)
        print('{} total chunk will be inserted, each chunk have {} rows.'.format(len(json_data), chunk))
        for iteration, chunk_ in enumerate(json_data, 1):
            conn = db_connection()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            insert_statement = cls.insert_string(table_def, table_name)
            start_time = time.time()
            cursor.executemany(insert_statement, chunk_)
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
            print(iteration, " %s seconds" % round((time.time() - start_time), 2))
        return print('Insert happened for survey sent.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DataLoader.process_survey_sent_data()
    DataLoader.insert_survey_sent_data()
#    DataLoader.run_post_sql()
```